# Newer edition of Zohar HaRakiah

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mitzvah

The [Rashbatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simeon_ben_Zemah_Duran) (Rabbi Shimon Ben Tzemach, 15th century) authored a commentary on [Rashbag](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_ibn_Gabirol)'s (Rabbi Shlomo ibn Gabirol, 11th century) *Azharos* (poem on the 613 mitzvos) called Zohar HaRakiah.

There's an old version on [HebrewBooks](http://hebrewbooks.org/30766) from 1879. I'm wondering if anyone ever republished a newer version and where to get it. I saw in the [Encyclopedia of the Taryag Mitzvos](https://www.google.com/search?q=1933296003&oq=1933296003) that they used the "Feldheim edition", which sounds new, but I couldn't find it on [their site](https://www.feldheim.com) or on Google.

Comment: Yes, there is a newer edition (I have it). A wonderful added bonus of the newer edition is the notes of [R. Yosef Rosen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogatchover_Gaon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://tablet.otzar.org/he/book/book.php?book=618742) is the Feldheim edition. There are also a number of other new editions with notes.

Comment: Is it out of print? Why can't I find it on their website